# Can I define a Map type that must include a certain value in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have the following code:

```
type SupportedUnits = Map<string, BigNumber>;

class CurrencyTools{
private supportedUnits: SupportedUnits;
  /**
   * @constructor
   * @param supportedUnits - A map in which the keys are the unit names and the values are their ratio in relation to the main unit.
   */

  constructor(supportedUnits: SupportedUnits) {
    this.supportedUnits = supportedUnits;
  }

    getMainUnit(): string {
    const denomination = Array.from(this.supportedUnits.keys()).find(
      (key) => this.supportedUnits.get(key)?.toString() === '1'
    );

    return denomination || '';
  }
}
```

Is there some way to define the supportedUnits type in a way that I can just return the `denomination`(as opposed to `denomination || ''`?  In other words can the type somehow enforce that one of the values of the mapping is equal to '1' but still allow any key?

Comment: "*can the type somehow enforce that one of the values of the mapping is equal to '1' but still allow any key?*" - no, not really.

Comment: It would almost certainly be much more trouble than it's worth to try to express such an invariant in a way the compiler could verify.  Either you guard against the "impossible" situation at runtime (e.g., `if (denomination === undefined) throw new Error("OH NOEZ")`, or you *assert* that it's impossible (e.g., `return denomination!`), or you refactor to some other data structure where the guarantee is obvious (e.g., a `mainUnit` string and a `Map` of *other* units). I'd write this up as an answer if you want; let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's type is undefined if the key doesn't match. We as programmers know it can't happen, but the type checker doesn't.

If you write `denomination!` it should work. The `!` is the non-null assertion operator, and it tells the type checker that it can never be null or undefined.

Comment: This is bad advice. `!` just bypasses type checking. If the value really is impossible throwing an exception would makes sense